# Как использовать две базы данных в проекте ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Есть основная база данных PostgreSQL, требуется создать программно ее локальную копию, чтоб была возможность производить над ней все те же операции, что и в PostgreSQL. При этом должна изменяться только копия, а основная оставаться без изменений. Возможно ли такое сделать с помощью стандартных или подключаемых библиотек?

Comment: у вас одновременно должны быть подключены обе БД (основная и локальная) или вы будете переключаться?

Comment: Баз данных можно создать сколько угодно. Только что вы подразумеваете под локальной в контексте веб-приложения? Она должна быть создана на клиенте? Работать с ней хотите на JavaScript?

Comment: MrModest, должны быть обе подключены, чтоб можно было одновременно с ними работать, но сначала требуется произвести изменения в копии

Comment: Alexander Petrov, ну либо она должна лежать где-то на сервере вместе с сайтом (если это конечно можно назвать локальной БД), либо, я читал, что есть DataSet, и как-то можно через него.

Comment: Через connection string подключите обе, и обращайтесь до нужной